# Empty rows at datatable fetching data from API

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, datatable, axios, vuetify.js

I'm getting data fetched from my API to have it appeared in my datatable but still, the rows are empty, when I inspect the network, it seems that the data is passed through but my page shows nothing inside the datatable, here's my code

```
<template>
<div>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-card style="margin-top: 2vh">
            <v-row justify="space-between">
                <v-card-title style="margin-left: 2vh">
                    Liste des fournitures
                </v-card-title>
            </v-row>
            <v-data-table 
                :headers="headers" 
                :items="supplies"
               >
            </v-data-table>
        </v-card>
    </v-container>
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

import Vue from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
export default Vue.extend({
  name: "Supplies",
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
        { text: "Supply Id", value: "SupplyId" },
        { text: "Nom", value: "Label" },
        { text: "Prix", value: "PriceId" },
        { text: "Créé le", value: "CreatedAt" },
        { text: "Modifié le", value: "EditedAt" },
    ],
    supplies: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    async getSupplyData() {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    await axios.get("https://localhost:7224/api/Supplies")
        .then((response) => (this.supplies = response.data));
    },
  },
  mounted() {
     this.getSupplyData();
  }

  });
 </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I typed the values variables in PascalCase, and in front end coding, always use camelCase except Classes and Interfaces